# Disminuir ancho de grafico en highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, highcharts

Esta imagen representa el gráfico de barras que tengo en mi sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si el highcharts trae una opción para poder manejar el ancho que hay entre barras del grafico, ya que veo que hay mucha distancia entre ellos y quisiera reducirlo para que esten mas pegados.

Como puedo hacer para disminuir el ancho de mi gráfica?

Les dejo mi codigo Javascript donde traigo la data y defino el grafico.

Dejo codigo JS:

```
    @section('js')
    
<script>
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#20c997', 'rgb(127,178,186)', 'rgb(254,176,83)', 'rgb(218,109,133)', '#28a745', '#e83e8c', '#dc3545', '#17a2b8', '#64E572', '#9F9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
    });
    Highcharts.chart('reproceso', {
        lang: {
            downloadCSV: "Descarga CSV",
            downloadXLS: "Descarga formato excel XLS",
            viewFullscreen: "Ver en pantalla completa",
            downloadPNG: "Descargar imagen PNG",
            downloadJPEG: "Descargar imagen JPEG",
            downloadPDF: "Descargar documento PDF",
            downloadSVG: "Descargar imagen SVG",
            downloadCSV: "Descargar formato excel CSV",
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            align: 'left',
            text: 'REPROCESOS EN LA FABRICACIÓN DE <?= $project->name ?>'
        },
        subtitle: {
            align: 'left',
            text: 'Ver actividades con reprocesos'
        },
        accessibility: {
            announceNewData: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total de reprocesos'
            }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.f}'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: cantidad <b>{point.y:.f} reproceso(s)</b><br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Reproceso en trabajo',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: <?= $dataR ?>,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'orange',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px'
                }
            }
        }],

    });
</script>
@stop
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con esta visualización.

Gracias

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es reducir el ancho del contenedor donde se renderiza la gráfica, ya que por defecto el diseño es **responsive** y se acopla al contenedor padre.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es modificar el **padding** de cada barra con `pointPadding`, dependiendo del tamaño de tu contenedor y tamaño de gráfico aumentas o disminuyes la medida, en este caso la deje en `-0.3` ya que `-0.4` las encima.

Por ejemplo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Highcharts 教程 | 本教程(w3big.com)</title>
  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src=" https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var chart = {
        type: 'column'
      };
      var title = {
        text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
      };
      var xAxis = {
        categories: ['Seattle HQ', 'San Francisco', 'Tokyo']
      };
      var yAxis = [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Employees'
        }
      }, {
        title: {
          text: 'Profit (millions)'
        },
        opposite: true
      }];
      var legend = {
        shadow: false
      };
      var tooltip = {
        shared: true
      };
      var credits = {
        enabled: false
      };
      var plotOptions = {
        column: {
          grouping: false,
          shadow: false,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      };
      var series = [{
        name: 'Employees Optimized',
        color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
        data: [140, 90, 40],
        pointPadding: -0.3,
        pointPlacement: 0

      }];

      var json = {};
      json.chart = chart;
      json.title = title;
      json.xAxis = xAxis;
      json.yAxis = yAxis;
      json.credits = credits;
      json.legend = legend;
      json.tooltip = tooltip;
      json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
      json.series = series;
      $('#container').highcharts(json);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Dime si te sirvio.